# Hexagon grid gets cut off when generation runs off out of the frame

Tags: java

I'm programming a hex-grid based game where you click on adjacent tiles to the player and when the player moves the map/grid moves in the opposite direction (using setLocation() on the jpanel inside the main jframe) so that, relative to the screen, the player is still centered. I pass into my GameBoard class constructor the max number of hexagons tall I want the grid to be in the middle and the radius of the individual hexagons and it works perfectly fine (to an extent).

When I pass in a big enough number of hexagons some of the grid generates outside of the jframe (which is as tall and as wide as a regular 1080x1920 sized monitor). When this happens, I can still make the player move around and open the menu and change player skins, but when moving north on the grid (when the top of the grid is what got generated outside the jframe) the grid just gets cut off and ends before the whole hexagon gets repainted.

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this that maybe I've simply just overlooked. My first thought was to delete and then regenerate the grid with new x,y coordinates each time the player moves and not use setLocation() method at all, but I feel like that would be very inefficient and more of a brute force solution (last resort). I just feel like there has to be a more elegant or efficient way. Even the slightest nudge in a general direction would be greatly appreciated. I've definitely played around with the setSize(), setMinimumSize(), and setPreferredSize() methods to try and make the jpanel or the jframe's content pane bigger.

Picture to help:

[image: You can see that I can obviously highlight those hexagons and even move onto them and move back off as illustrated by the player's path being shown.]

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ by the way

Answer (score 0):

The solution really depends on your specific requirements. You do need to distinguish between the visible window and the virtual canvas though. You can imagine your view frame being a window on top of a world that is bigger than what you see.

If the size of your map is known from the beginning, create a buffer/frame that can fit it based on that.

If the size is not known beforehand or it's infinite, then you'll need procedural generation of tiles. When saying tiles I don't mean the hex tiles, but the buffer/frame you paint them on. Once the border of a frame is hit, you'd need to attach a new one on that side.

Comment: In my case I know what the size is going to be based on the number of hexagons and radius passed in.

Comment: Well then you just need to calculate the required buffer/pane/frame/canvas (name it however you want) size and use that. Using screen size only works for the "window", not for the "world".